# Parsing configuration file using pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am trying to use pyparsing to parse a configuration file of following form

```
x = "/user/test"
y = 3
```

Here is my code snippet

```
ParserElement.defaultWhitespaceChars = (" \t")
END = StringEnd()
NL = LineEnd().suppress()
assignment = Literal('=')

key_str = CharsNotIn("=")
value_str = Group(~assignment + restOfLine)

line = Group(key_str + assignment + value_str)
lines = ZeroOrMore(line)
lines.ignore(NL)

text = """
y = 3
x = 2
"""
```

The output that I get from parseFile tells me it is parsing the first line only. Can anybody please help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Would you be averse to using a library that can already parse files that look sort of like this?  For example https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/

Comment: Thank you for your input.There are additional parsing work I am doing (e.g. parsing of a scheduler log, some script files etc). In that context I am trying to get a better understanding of pyparsing for last few weeks. I consider myself a novice in pyparsing area so wanted to get some pointers about what I did wrong here.

Comment: @AbhijitBhattacharya - search SO for other questions/answers with the `pyparsing` tag. You can also visit the wiki at http://pyparsing.wikispace.com, and read through the Discussion tab on the wiki Home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track. Maybe you are doing something wrong when you acutally pass the `text` to the grammar. Adding the following line in your code

```
print lines.parseString(text)
```

Gives the expected output

```
[['y ', '=', [' 3']], ['x ', '=', [' 2']]]
```

As an aside, normally you *don't* want to keep the whitespace when parsing. The tokens are usually the only thing that matters. This is how I would parse your example:

```
EOL = LineEnd().suppress()
EQ  = Literal("=").suppress()
val = Word(alphanums)
line = Group(val('key') + EQ + val('val') + EOL)
grammar = OneOrMore(line)

for x in grammar.parseString(text):
    print x.dump()
```

The output in this case is much nicer

```
['y', '3']
- key: y
- val: 3
['x', '2']
- key: x
- val: 2
```

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Typically the protocol is to upvote useful answers and "accept" an answer that solves your problem.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a different approach at the grammar.

Comment: I accepted your answer. As for the upvote, I guess there is something called "reputation" for newcomers. Without that it doen't allow upvoting.

Comment: @AbhijitBhattacharya I didn't know there was a rep limit for upvoting your own question's answers. According to the FAQ, http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation, you'll need at least 15 rep to do so... looks like you're halfway there!

Comment: @Hooked - nicely done, good use of results names, and good point about whitespace usually not being part of the grammar definition. Minor tip: `Literal('=').suppress()` can also be written `Suppress('=')`, but either way works just as well.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks for the tip! One thing I couldn't figure out when making the example was how to properly name the `line` under the `OneOrMore`. Even if I gave it a name, when I tried to `.dump()` the whole parse result I ended up getting only a single result, hence why I had to iterate through it.

Comment: Try naming it "line*" - the trailing asterisk is a flag to pyparsing to keep all values, not just the last one; it is a shorthand for calling `setResultsName` with `listAllMatches=True`. Also, I overlooked one other point - the original question also had a RHS value of a quoted string as one of the examples. You can accommodate this by adding `| quotedString` to the definition of `val`.